# Unable to access Jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Error: Unable to access Jarfile ApacheJMeter.jar
Errorlevel=1
How i can remove this error with current version of Jmeter 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your installation is corrupt, double check the following:

1. You have Java SDK or JRE version 7 (or higher), you can get the latest Java from [Java SE Download Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). If you execute `java -version` command you should see something like:

   > C:>java -version
   >
   > java version "**1.8**.0_112"
   >
   > Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)
   >
   > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b15, mixed mode)

   Highlighted in **bold** numbers should be not less than **1.7**
2. Double check downloaded JMeter bundle [MD5 checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5), it should be equal to the one which is provided at [JMeter Downloads page](https://www.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-3.1.zip.md5)
3. Try running JMeter without help of startup scripts by executing the following command from JMeter's "bin" folder

   ```
   java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
   ```

See

- [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans)

  for step-by-step JMeter setup instructions